# How many meta-query fields support WordPress search at a time?

Tags: metabox, search, meta-query

I am new developer. I want know How many meta-query fields support WordPress search at a time?

I saw that its getting (500 time out) errors after nine fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no hard limit, but meta queries are very inefficient, and in my experience things start to slow down dramatically after 3 or 4, depending on what type of query they are exactly (`=`, `LIKE` etc.)

For querying based on that many fields you should consider a custom table, rather than meta. Or taxonomies where appropriate for the type of data being used.

Comment: Thanks!  I have 20 fields. Which way is the better for search between metabox and taxonomies ?

Comment: Taxonomies will be faster, but you're assigning pre-existing terms to posts to filter by. So they're not appropriate for things like prices or coordinates, since the values will be unique to posts. If all your data is unique to posts then you'll want to implement a custom table, but it'll be quite a bit of work to integrate with queries.